# Is it possible to have $\text{transcendental}^\text{transcendental} =\text{algebraic}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, solution-verification, exponentiation, irrational-numbers, transcendental-numbers

We know that it possible to have $\text{irrational}^\text{irrational}=\text{rational}$.

To verify the possibility of this, we consider the expression $\sqrt{2}^\sqrt{2}$, if it is rational, then this step completes the verification. If $\sqrt{2}^\sqrt{2}$ is irrational, then we take a further step which is raising it to the power $\sqrt{2}$ which is irrational,

we get $\sqrt{2}^{\sqrt{2}^\sqrt{2}}=\sqrt{2}^2=2$ which is rational. This completes the verification.

The question that pops up into my mind is:

Is it possible to have $\text{transcendental}^\text{transcendental} =\text{algebraic}$?

I could not reach the answer with the same logic (as dealing with irrationals).

Any help would be appropriated. THANKS.

Comment: By the way, you do not get ${\sqrt2}^{{\sqrt2}^{\sqrt 2}}$, you get $\left({\sqrt2}^{\sqrt2}\right)^{\sqrt2}$.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes: $e$ and $\ln2$ are trascendental and $e^{\ln 2}=2$. Also $e^{i\pi}=-1$.

Comment: $e^{\ln(2)}=2$, how trivial is that, why did not come in mind! THANKS a lot.

Comment: I'd call it "well-known", because I don't classify any assertion about a specific number being trascendental as "trivial".